# Merge view-model and viewmodels tags into the viewmodel tag

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, retag-request

I believe [viewmodel](/questions/tagged/viewmodel) is the correct tag. 823 questions tagged are with [viewmodel](/questions/tagged/viewmodel).

[view-model](/questions/tagged/view-model) has 21 questions tagged with it.
[viewmodels](/questions/tagged/viewmodels) has 13 questions tagged with it

Please [view-model](/questions/tagged/view-model) and [viewmodels](/questions/tagged/viewmodels) tags into the [viewmodel](/questions/tagged/viewmodel) tag

Comment: Trying to bump this to get the request noticed.

Comment: That's a pretty trivial number of questions.  This can easily be done by hand.  Unless anyone else wants to handle it, I'll go through the questions tomorrow evening.  There's some pretty bad tagging in some of these...

Comment: I guess I would need some more reputation to do that. How is it done by the way?

Comment: Quite literally by editing the question, removing the old tags and adding the new tags.  Tag edits [require 500 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions).  Keep in mind that these are still considered edits, and will thus bump the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have the retag privilege and will handle it. Earlier I was thinking more along the lines of some moderator action.

Comment: So once I do this, the tags that have no question associated, get removed automatically I suppose.

Comment: That is correct.  After about a day, they'll disappear.  `view-model` can never be created again -- it's a duplicate of the same tag without the hyphen -- but `viewmodels` could be recreated.  Don't worry about that one, we members of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal will keep it from happening.

Comment: Haha. More power to you!

Comment: I am done retagging the `view-model` and `viewmodels` tags to `viewmodel`.